# arduino auto format equivalent in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, autoformatting

I´m having trouble formating my code.

```
For example:
  for i in range(len(text)):
    text[i] = text[i].strip('"')
    text[i] = text[i].strip()
  print text, len(text)
  opreg_addr = int(text[2], 16)
  var_from = int(text[3])
  var_to = int(text[4])
  opvar_index = int(text[5])
  bms.opvars[opvar_index] = bms.readbits(var_from, var_to, bms.opreg[opreg_addr]);
```

I forgot to place a for loop before this code like for i in range(num_lines):
When i use auto_indent or reformat code it only indents the first line after my for loop even though i marked the whole context. In the Arduino IDE auto format works like a charm, how to do that in pycharm ? (i set code style indents = 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not auto format Python code because the indentation defines the scope. This cannot automaticly guessed.

For example for C, C++ and C# the scope is defined using { and } the identation does not really matter. So there you can auto format.

Comment: Thx. How to indent a selected text by 2 spaces ?

Comment: I don't know in PyCharm but in Eclipse for example you can set the tab with to 2. You can then select the lines and press tab.

Comment: Yeah i kind of overlooked that option when setting my indents, works like a charm.